# Decrease font size in "nodes near coords" in bar chart #tikzpicture #pgfplots

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I was trying to decrease the size of the font in **nodes near coords** in the following code, but the only solution that I found to avoid the nodes numbers overlap was to decrease their number of decimal digits.

Any suggestions on how to decrease the font of **nodes near coords** ?

```
\newcommand{\figureHeight}{0.5625} %% 16:9
\pgfplotsset{
    compat           = 1.13,
    grid             = major,
    enlarge x limits = 0,
    cycle list name  = tum,
    major grid style = {dotted},
    minor grid style = {dotted},
    width            = \hsize,
    %width            = \hsize * 0.9,
    height           = \hsize * 0.9 * \figureHeight,
    legend style     = { at = {(0.98,0.96)}, anchor = north east,}
}

\begin{figure}[thb]
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar               = 5pt, % configures `bar shift'
    xmajorgrids        = false,
    x tick label style = {
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep =},
    xtick              = { 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018},
    ylabel             = Energy Produced in TWh,
    enlarge x limits   = 0.1,
    ymin               = 0,
    ymax               = 125,
    bar width          = 4pt,
    legend style={at={(0.02,0.96)},anchor=north west},
    nodes near coords
    ]

    %Hidro
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 18 ) ( 2012 , 21 ) ( 2013 , 23 ) ( 2014 , 19 ) ( 2015 , 19 ) ( 2016 , 21 ) ( 2017 , 20 ) ( 2018 , 19 )};
    \addlegendentry{Hydro}

    %Biomass
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 34 ) ( 2012 , 40 ) ( 2013 , 41 ) ( 2014 , 43 ) ( 2015 , 44 ) ( 2016 , 45 ) ( 2017 , 45 ) ( 2018 , 45 )};
    \addlegendentry{Biomass}

    %Wind
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 50 ) ( 2012 , 52 ) ( 2013 , 53 ) ( 2014 , 59 ) ( 2015 , 81 ) ( 2016 , 80 ) ( 2017 , 106 ) ( 2018 , 111 )};
    \addlegendentry{Wind}

    %Solar
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 20 ) ( 2012 , 26 ) ( 2013 , 31 ) ( 2014 , 36 ) ( 2015 , 40 ) ( 2016 , 38 ) ( 2017 , 39 ) ( 2018 , 46 )};
    \addlegendentry{Solar}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Energy from renewable sources in Germany}

    \label{fig:EnergyFromRenewablesGermany}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the style with `nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}` (or whatever size you like)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\figureHeight}{0.5625} %% 16:9
\pgfplotsset{
    compat           = 1.13,
    grid             = major,
    enlarge x limits = 0,
%    cycle list name  = tum,
    major grid style = {dotted},
    minor grid style = {dotted},
    width            = \hsize,
    %width            = \hsize * 0.9,
    height           = \hsize * 0.9 * \figureHeight,
    legend style     = { at = {(0.98,0.96)}, anchor = north east,},
}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[thb]
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar               = 5pt, % configures `bar shift'
    xmajorgrids        = false,
    x tick label style = {
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep =},
    xtick              = { 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018},
    ylabel             = Energy Produced in TWh,
    enlarge x limits   = 0.1,
    ymin               = 0,
    ymax               = 125,
    bar width          = 4pt,
    legend style={at={(0.02,0.96)},anchor=north west},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}    
    ]

    %Hidro
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 18 ) ( 2012 , 21 ) ( 2013 , 23 ) ( 2014 , 19 ) ( 2015 , 19 ) ( 2016 , 21 ) ( 2017 , 20 ) ( 2018 , 19 )};
    \addlegendentry{Hydro}

    %Biomass
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 34 ) ( 2012 , 40 ) ( 2013 , 41 ) ( 2014 , 43 ) ( 2015 , 44 ) ( 2016 , 45 ) ( 2017 , 45 ) ( 2018 , 45 )};
    \addlegendentry{Biomass}

    %Wind
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 50 ) ( 2012 , 52 ) ( 2013 , 53 ) ( 2014 , 59 ) ( 2015 , 81 ) ( 2016 , 80 ) ( 2017 , 106 ) ( 2018 , 111 )};
    \addlegendentry{Wind}

    %Solar
    \addplot coordinates { ( 2011 , 20 ) ( 2012 , 26 ) ( 2013 , 31 ) ( 2014 , 36 ) ( 2015 , 40 ) ( 2016 , 38 ) ( 2017 , 39 ) ( 2018 , 46 )};
    \addlegendentry{Solar}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Energy from renewable sources in Germany}

    \label{fig:EnergyFromRenewablesGermany}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam, it helps me to solve my problem. But is there a solution that changes the font locally (For this specific graph), but keeps the default unchanged for the rest of the document?

Comment: @leao.gloria Sure, use `nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}` in the optional argument of the axis